# Cannot get my hamburger menu to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://darrenbachan.com/playground/zeckoshop/template.html

I'm having an issue with my hamburger menu. It appears on mobile. I have .js set so when you click on it, it toggles a class that adds position:fixed to stop the site from scrolling. I am not sure if this is the issue of it's CSS, but when the menu is open, and I've added enough li's to warrant a scroll, I can't scroll on it.

Any ideas? On my phone it just cuts off and won't allow a scroll.

Comment: show preview in jsfiddle for better help

Comment: you don't want site to scroll when you have icon opened on mobile?

Comment: I don't. I've been in inspector for hours now, I realized that .outer-menu .menu has a fixed position that's making the actual menu not capable of scrolling, it's either that or .outer-menu .menu > div because of the width and height. Still trying to tinker on my end to figure it out.

As for a fiddle, I ripped the css/html from here http://codepen.io/brenden/pen/VLjKMQ but this example doesn't have a lot of <li>'s to show a scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to put `overflow-y: auto;` on following class.

```
.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0 1em;
margin: 0;
display: block;
max-height: 100vh;
overflow-y: auto;
```

}

Comment: The overflow:hidden; helped with removing the Android's refresh action, but the menu itself you still can't scroll in it.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I tried locally and live updating the code.

Comment: Check this image, this is what you want right? http://imgur.com/yKOxsuh

sorry, it should be `overflow-y` . Check answer.

Comment: This sort of works in Chrome's device mode trying to emulate iPhone 6 if I click on the right spot and scroll, but when I push the code live and test on my Android it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you push this to prod so I can check on my mobile device?

Comment: http://darrenbachan.com/playground/zeckoshop/template.html Hey I have it uploaded here, but the real test is taking a look on mobile. If possible could we chat over Twitter dm or Skype?

Comment: I got your issue You are half way done! It is not scrolling menu as it is scrolling background contents. Let me try last then we can talk on Twitter.

Comment: I think the overflow-y: auto you added makes the background contents scrolled, I don't want the background to scroll, I need the menu to scroll. I don't know why it won't though.

Comment: I got solution. Did you remember I asked you to add `overflow:hidden` to body. Now, can you add this while keeping `overflow-y` to menu?

Comment: Just to clarify, I have a toggle class to make body.fixed happen when the menu icon is clicked on. That's what you want me to add overflow: hidden to? I haven't removed it since you told me to add it on. Now, which class would I add overflow-y too?

Comment: When your menu appears then it should have `overflow-y: auto` and at the same time your `body` should have `overflow: hidden`